# Rotated div causes horizontal scrollbar in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

I have a div (#shortcuts) outside my container div which is rotated 90 degrees. Here's the basic idea:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="shortcuts">Some links</div>
    <div id="content">The main content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css on #shortcuts:

```
#shortcuts {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1020px;
    top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    display: table;
    /* each link within the div is a table-cell */
}
```

In Internet Explorer 11, it is creating a horizontal scrollbar. The reason is that it is rendering the width of the #shortcuts div *before* it rotates it.

As a "cheap fix," I've set #wrapper to `overflow: hidden`. However, I would prefer that to not be set because a smaller window *should* create a horizontal scrollbar if needed.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0drcch87/4/

Comment: could you provide a working demo? Also, your unprefixed version of transform should be declared after any prefixed versions.

Comment: @jbutler483 I can't provide the actual site, but here is the same problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0drcch87/4

Comment: If you're going for the 'cheap fix' or targeting just IE then -ms-overflow-x is an option

Comment: Well I would rather fix it properly (if there is a "proper" way to fix it). However, your fix is better than mine (in that, yours at least only affects IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#shortcuts {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 320px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 102%;
    display: table;
}
```

Refer : https://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/0drcch87/8/

Comment: Hmm, that fixes the fiddle, but not my actual site. That should give me somewhere to go from here, though. Thanks!

Comment: It may be fixed with "transform-origin" property and proper left and top position

Comment: Wow, yes, I just had to adjust my top and left positions. Thank you! Now on to figure out exactly how transform-origin works.